# Datatable not showing any but the model is filled with data

Tags: c#, html, sql, model-view-controller, datatable

**here's my button to way to script:**

```
<div class="col-xs-1">
    <label></label>
    <button type="submit" id="" onclick="GetReport()" class="btn btn-block btn-
    primary">Getir</button> 
    <!-- /.input group -->
</div>
```

**here's my script:**

```
function GetReport() {
    var efirm = document.getElementById("Firmalar");
    var FirmValue = efirm.options[efirm.selectedIndex].value;
    var gonderilendegiskenler = {
        FirmValue: FirmValue
    }
    $.ajax({
        url: '/AnaMenu/ServisRaporT', 
        type: 'post',
        data: gonderilendegiskenler,        
        success: function () {
            window.location.href = '/AnaMenu/ServisRaporT';
        }
    })
}
```

**here's my controller:**

```
public ActionResult ServisRaporT(string FirmValue)
{
    var user = (from u in db.Servis
        where u.ServisFirma == FirmValue
        select u).ToList();
    return View(user);
}
```

**here's my view:**

```
@model IEnumerable<FG.Models.Servis>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "ServisRaporT";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<div class="content-wrapper">
    <!-- Content Header (Page header) -->
    <section class="content-header">
        <h1>
        Servis Raporları
        </h1>
    </section>
    <!-- Main content -->
    <section class="content">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <!-- /.box -->
                <div class="box box-primary">
                    <!-- /.box-header -->
                    <div class="box-body">
                        <table id="example1" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Firma</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                            @foreach (var item in Model)
                            {
                                <tr>
                                    <td>@item.ServisTarih</td>
                                </tr>
                            }
                        </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.box-body -->
                </div>
                <!-- /.box -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.col -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.row -->
    </section>
    <!-- /.content -->
</div>
```

everything seems right, i mean the model is showing me that its filled with data from the controller but when i check the page i cant see any data in table. and i dont know why? can you please help me?

Comment: Something is not right with your flow.  On success, you do `window.location.href = '/AnaMenu/ServisRaporT'` which does a `GET` request to the same endpoint that you're doing a `POST` on.  One way is to return JSON form your `POST` and re-render your view that way.

Comment: can you please share the way to do that?

Comment: @RifKohen - here are some examples - https://www.google.com/search?q=.net+mvc+updating+a+div+with+ajax+result+example&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-ab&gfe_rd=cr&ei=doIxWYTcKcnI8AeR8JbIAQ

Comment: @RifKohen Many Javascript frameworks support rendering views from JSON data: Angular, React, etc.  I don't suggset rolling your own. But the basic idea is you have a JSON object, and you need to present it in the view.